# Launch GotoMeeting from Calendar

Tags: google-calendar, gotomeeting

I have a number of GotoMeeting meetings that I have in my Google Calendar. I'm using the GTM app on my phone and I'd like to be able to launch the GTM app with the meeting ID already filled in from Calendar.

Is this possible?